# Common practice for setting environment variables in Django?

Tags: django

I'm very new to the Django framework. I am writing an app, and I would like to set a number of environment variables before the server is run. Is there a standardized approach to doing this (i.e. a setup script that is run before the server startup is completed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon webserver you want to use. For example apache with mod_wsgi you can add your variables in the `os.environ`. Refer [WSGI IntegrationWithDjango](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango)

However, in general updating `os.environ` in `setttings.py` would also work.

Comment: Bad idea. This puts your plaintext secrets in settings.py, source code that could be readable by a lot of people, especially if you accidentally push it to a public github repo.

Comment: @hobs, why do you put secret in the code that you want to publish on public forum? Secrets should be kept secret. The answer is for other configuration.

Comment: I don't. Even if your "other configuration" truly isn't useful to a hacker, if it's not used by django, then settings.py is the wrong place for it anyway. Env vars should be set in your virtualenv postactivate or some other shell script. It's not python code. It's environment provisioning.